# SQL subquery and reverse order in group of query

Tags: sql, subquery

writing a chat program, i want to show the last 5 (example) records order in DESC (the new in bottom and continuing upon others).

I use this line but did'n work:

```
Show.Open("SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY id DESC) AS q ORDER BY q.id ASC",Cn,1);
```

(selecting only 5 record counting with i++)

Or using a single "SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY id DESC" but loading the records from the first to the last of the group)..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the number of rows, do it in the sub-query - and combine it with order by.

(Otherwise a sub-query's ORDER BY makes no sense at all.)

ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY id DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Below  query may solve it:

SELECT  * FROM database (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM database ORDER BY id DESC) ORDER BY id ASC